# Difference between GMT and UTC in Android

Tags: android, date, time, utc, gmt

The function **System.currentTimeMillis()** returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

The function **Date.getTime()** returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 GMT midnight.

This is what Android's documentation says.

So where is the difference? Can I calculate with them or is there an offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most intents and purposes the two are equivalent.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Definition_and_relationship_to_other_standards